# Flutter/Dart convert future bool to bool

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Can some one help me to identify the issue in below piece of code

```
void main() async {
  bool c =getstatus();
  print(c);
  }

Future<bool> getMockData() {
  return Future.value(false);
}

bool getstatus() async   
{
  Future<bool> stringFuture = getMockData();
  bool message =  stringFuture;
  return(message); // will print one on console.

}
```

Comment: Converting Future to a bool is not logical statement (It's not like converting String to an int..), waiting for the future result is. And that's the problem here you're not waiting for the result, here you're using async without await.. `bool message =  await stringFuture` will wait until the result is ready and assign it to the bool variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get values from a `Future`(async) method, you have to `await` them. And after *await* the variable you get is not a Future anymore. So basically your code should look like this:

```dart
void main() async {
  bool c = await getstatus();
  print(c);
}

Future<bool> getMockData() {
  return Future.value(false);
}

Future<bool> getstatus() async {
  bool message = await getMockData();
  return message;
}
```

Comment: `bool c = await getstatus();` , getstatus() returns a bool not a future why using await?

Comment: @fsbelinda  tried this code here https://dartpad.dev/? still its not working :(

Comment: `void main() async {
  bool c = await getstatus();
  print(c);
  }

Future<bool> getMockData() {
  return Future.value(false);
}

Future<bool> getstatus() async   
{
  bool message =  await getMockData();
  return(message); // will print one on console.

}`

Comment: @Sandeep Ks I re-edited my answer. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

an async method must return Future of something then in the main you have to get the bool value by writing await

```
   void main() async {
      bool c = await getstatus();
      print(c); // will print false on the console.
    }
    
    Future<bool> getMockData() {
      return Future.value(false);
    }
    
    Future<bool> getstatus() async {
      Future<bool> stringFuture = await getMockData();
   
      return stringFuture; // will return false.
    }
```

Comment: tried this code here https://dartpad.dev/? still its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<bool> stringFuture = await getMockData();
```

Comment: Thanks But tried this code here dartpad.dev? still its not working